# Modifying (adding) module's content before module is rendered ? Is this possible ?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

I want to **catch module content** before being rendered in page ? I know i can override module contents but this solution doesn't fit my requirements. I want to catch certain module say mod_modname's content **before rendering in page** so that i can **alter** content.

Is this **possible** ? Is there any **events** we can **trigger** ? Any help will be appreciated ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is [Applying custom module chrome](https://docs.joomla.org/Applying_custom_module_chrome)

With that you can change the content before displaying it: **$module->content**

Comment: is this possible with joomla core module? like login module of joomla ?

Comment: Yes, it works on all modules you load in that module position with your custom type.